# Collect metrics from the openstack environment and show it in grafana

Tags: openstack, metrics, grafana, collect

Let me define first what is my goal:
I want to have pretty Grafana dashboards about our openstack clusters. We have 5 datacenters with around 3-4000 physical machine and 15k vm-s. My task is to create some pretty Grafana dashboards fo mysql things, rabbit mq things and of course about the openstack performance, instance counts … We want to use it for capacity planning os something like that, for example in the last 1 year how many xxlarge vm-s were requested in each tenant.

The last week I read a lot about this because I completely new in this area and now I completely got lost regarding the objects, gnocchi, ceilometer, telemetry, aodh, collectd, Prometheus, influxdb … so in my head at the moment I have a completely big mess.

Our current Grafana infrastructure is actually built, I should integrate our openstack stuffs into it.

1. Collectd is running everywhere
2. Graphite is collecting the collect things
3. Grafana is reading the graphite

I can modify, add more source to the graphite server, but please help me, what should I do, which is the best was to make it work?

I’ve tried dashboards imported from Grafana but I can’t make it work, it always show idiot information.

So how is should collect the data? Gnocchi or collectd or something else?

If I collect with gnocchi do I have to add new source for graphite where we have the data?

Do I need aodh or ceilometer (telemetry)?

Our DC-s looks like the following:

- 2 Controller nodes running neutron, nova, keystone
- Separated load balancers
- separated rabbit mq
- separated db servers

Comment: Using collectd in every machines to send metrics to central Graphite cluster is a sophisticated solution. In my team, we have a Graphite cluster which could bear 1M metrics in every second and developers could use Grafana to view the realtime metrics. I don't really understand your confusion, you can specify it and I may help you.

Comment: My confuse is what tool I should use to collect the openstack related data for grafana? Gnocchi or collect or both? For example I want to see how long it usually take one spawning, or I want to see the available resources, or want to see rabbitmq queue...

Comment: It depends. In our cases, we should use collectd to send metrics about os, and use StatsD client to send metrics in our source code. Regarding other infrastructure, like rabbitmq, there may be some tools or built-in helper to allow you send their metrics to StatsD or something else. So I don’t think one tool could easily solve such complicated problems.

Comment: So you mean the collectd would be good for the os related things? Statsd I should use for example checking the sapwning time or for capacity planning?

Comment: I didn't make a decision for you because I couldn't. I just hope you can analyze your demand and choose the simplest tools, maybe more than one. For example, collectd provides plugins to support many many datasources, and you could also write some own plugins if possible. You could find whether it can support all your demands. I didn't really know about openstack, but if I were you, I will have a look what collectd can do, and what StatsD can do, and what Graphite can do. If you are clear about those things and your demand, you can make a good decision naturally.

Answer (score 0):

There is a framework for telemetry, actually called [Service Telemetry Framework](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_openstack_platform/16.1/html-single/service_telemetry_framework_1.3/index), supported by Red Hat. It potentially covers all your requirements.
Though, it works on OpenShift only.